# DatagridView data transfer

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to take data from a DGV from one form to Texboxes of another form
this is what I've done:

```
int o = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells["AccountName"].Value.ToString()
obj.txtTranType.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells["TransactionType"].Value.ToString();
obj.txtDateTime.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells["TransactionDate"].Value.ToString();
obj.txtTranAmt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells["TransactionAmount"].Value.ToString();
obj.txtCurrAmt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells["CurrentAmount"].Value.ToString();
obj.txtAvailAmt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells["AvailableAmount"].Value.ToString();
obj.txtClientID.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells["ClientID"].Value.ToString();
```

when I return to the form with the textboxes nothing is diplayed in them, I don't know why.

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[o].Cells, you mean dataGridView1.Rows[0]?

Comment: @learningNew no, 'o' is the index of the selected row

Comment: You need to use reference of the same form in which you collect the data.

Comment: Can u access the cell index of a datagridview cell by name or do you have to use the index for that as well.

Comment: @user3681092 'o' can not be the index, 0 (Zero) can be.

Comment: What is `obj` variable?

Comment: Line 2 isn't setting a var

Comment: @learningNew you are misleading me and

Comment: @WCEM2040 yes you can

Comment: Please show more code regarding `obj`

Comment: @MitatKoyuncu its `Form1 obj = new Form1();`

Comment: No, that's a mistake, get reference from previous form and then initialize `obj` from it

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid how?

Comment: You can use constructor.

Comment: Where do you call `obj.Show()` and where do you initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is async or on button click, or whatever.

But for async add a method to the event of the datagrid, that sets the textbox of the form to the value of the datagrow row by referencing the index value.

Missing quite a bit of the requirements, so it's hard to provide you with complete code examples.

Comment: its on a button click

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem regarding `obj` as mentioned in the comments then try this example to pass the object to the form as `obj`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 obj;
    public Form1(Form2 form2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        obj = form2;
    }
    //declare your method here as you show in code to get values from gridview using obj
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LaunchForm1();
    }
    private void LaunchForm1()
    {
        var form1 = new Form1(this);
        form1.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```